# How to properly rename CodeModule of ThisWorksheet

Tags: excel, vbe, vba

I'm trying to rename the `ThisWorkbook` code module of an Excel worksheet using VBA Extensibility.

I accomplish this with the line

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").Name = "wb"
```

I can see the change in the VB editor and also access the workbook's properties, e.g. `Debug.? wb.Name`.

However: If I save and close the file and then reopen it, I get strange behavior. If the code module was empty before renaming it, it reverts back to the old empty `ThisWorkbook` name.

If it was not empty or was populate before the saving, I now have both, an empty `ThisWorkbook` module (that would fire events if there were any) - and the filled `wb` module - which does not fire workbook events:

[image]

Has anyone seen this behavior - and knows a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Quick answer:** `ThisWorkbook.[_CodeName] = "newName"`

**Detailed answer**

When I add references to the `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3` and run your line

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").Name = "wb"
```

The `ThisWorkbook` Name property isn't actually being modified

[image]

Saving and re-opening the file causes a duplication of the `ThisWorkbook` object

[image]

Which pretty much means now I have two `Workbook` objects within one workbook and both are named `ThisWorkbook`

---

The workaround is to rename the `ThisWorkbook` to `wb` using the *Properties* window or

`ThisWorkbook.[_CodeName] = "newName"` because `ThisWorkbook.CodeName` is read-only.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how does this evaluation of `_CodeName` work here? Do you have any links? Didn't know about this approach/hack!

Comment: @PeterAlbert well, it comes from experience I don't have any links unfortunately. If you open Object Browser and choose VBAProject Library at the top then right click anywhere and select Show Hidden Members. And navigate to CodeName. There are 2 one is ReadOnly and the other (hidden one) allows you to set this property. I just know that the hidden members are hidden because there is no official documentation on them and MS doesnt want developers to use them as they havent been fully tested etc.